# Does CHECK TABLE add read/write locks?

Tags: mysql

Yesterday I ran `CHECK TABLE` on a table that is read very frequently. I scanned the [MySQL documentation for `CHECK TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/check-table.html) for any mentions of "lock" (and found none) and also noticed that only `SELECT` privilege was required to run the command. I therefor concluded that the command did not do any read lock and was safe to run even in production.

Sadly, running the command took 1 minute and 37 seconds and seemed to block all read access. My question is therefor, does `CHECK TABLE` do any read lock? Any other reason why I experienced a read block on the table?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was most certainly that there was a big slow `SELECT` running through the table and `UPDATE`ing individual rows. Therefor, `CHECK TABLE` was locked on individual rows and took a long time.

The verdict; Never run `CHECK TABLE` if you are updating a whole lot of rows.